# Categories API only pulling 50 categories

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to pull all of the categories from my store via the API. But I can't seem to get it to work. I only get 50. Is there a limit to how many categories that can be pulled?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the API will return a maximum of 50 items for any resources requested via the API. To increase the number of returned categories you can include a **limit** parameter in your request. In addition you can also specify a **page** parameter to retrieve a particular page of results.

**Example**

To return the 2nd page of the categories with 10 results per page, you would make the following request

```
GET /categories.json?limit=10&page=2
```

Comment: Looks like there is still a limit of 250, but I can work with that. Thanks.