# bigcommerce requested resources increase limit 250

Tags: php, http-headers, bigcommerce

I was trying to increase my `API` resource request from 250 to all our listed product. I'm using a custom `PHP` application to achieve this.

I refer to this [pulling 50 categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17056786/categories-api-only-pulling-50-categories#)

This is what I did so far.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api/v2/products.json?limit=250';
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Bigcommerce is limited to 250...sorry https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#list-products

Comment: thanks for you response @forbs but that seems to be unfair. is there no other way? like overriding the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to request more than 250 at a time--this is a firm limit built into the API. What you can do though is use pagination and loop through each page until you've pulled all of the records. To pull the first page of 250 records, you would request:

`$url = 'https://example.com/api/v2/products.json?page=1&limit=250';`